# Graphics and sleep issues on Dell Inspiron 15 UHD

Tags: nvidia, suspend, inspiron

I'm having major issues getting a new Dell Inspiron 15 (7559) to work. This is the newest one, with the NVIDIA GTX 960M graphics, 6th Generation Intel Core i7-6700HQ Processor (skylake), 128GB SSD, 1TB HDD and 16GB RAM.

I'm trying to use it with Kubuntu 15.10. Initial boot from the Live USB drive required "nomodeset" in GRUB at startup, installation then went ok, with updates installed as part of the installation. This left "nomodeset" in the grub config, and using the nouveau drivers, which worked ok but rather slow, and the laptop would not resume from sleep, black screen and unresponsive on the network.

I've tried various combinations of Nvidia drivers (352, 355, 358), Kernel (4.2, 4.3, 4.4rc3), and having either "nomodeset", i915_preliminary_hw_enable=1 or none of those set on boot, but whatever I do I can't get the laptop into nvidia mode ("prime-select nvidia") without just getting a black screen, switching back to "prime-select intel" and I get graphics back. In all these combinations however I still don't get any graphics on resumption from sleep, however 4.4rc3 does result in the system responding on the network after resuming from sleep (intel mode, nomodeset), so it's a step in the right direction.

With Kernel 4.4 and Nvidia 358, no "nomodeset" with "i915.preliminary_hw_support=1", intel mode set. I get a freeze on startup, no X, text mode login prompt but no response from keyboard, no response on network.

As above, but with "nomodeset" enabled and i915.preliminary_hw_support=1. Black screen on boot, but response on network so system is up, just no display.

Dropping i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 on startup I get graphics in intel mode, but sleep still not working.

Xorg.0.log from 4.3rc3 intel mode nomodeset i915.preliminary_hw_support=1

```
   [    60.994] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
[    60.994] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    60.994] Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-68-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    60.994] Current Operating System: Linux aureus 4.4.0-040400rc3-generic #201511300321 SMP Mon Nov 30 03:23:36 UTC 2015 x86_64
[    60.994] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-040400rc3-generic root=UUID=f5d8e5f1-6325-4fc0-a785-0addfb0f32d7 ro nomodeset quiet splash i915.preliminary_hw_support=1
[    60.994] Build Date: 12 November 2015  05:33:29PM
[    60.994] xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1ubuntu9.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    60.994] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    60.994]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    60.994] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    60.994] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Dec  1 15:45:44 2015
[    60.994] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    60.994] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    60.994] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    60.994] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    60.994] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    60.995] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[    60.995] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    60.995] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    60.995] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    60.995] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    60.995]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.995] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    60.995]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.995] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    60.995]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.995] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    60.995]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.995] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    60.995]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    60.995] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[    60.995] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    60.995] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    60.995] (II) Loader magic: 0x55a51dd6cd40
[    60.995] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    60.995]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    60.995]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
[    60.995]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[    60.995]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    60.995] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    60.996] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:191b:1028:0706 rev 6, Mem @ 0xdd000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64
[    60.996] (--) PCI: (0:2:0:0) 10de:139b:1028:0706 rev 162, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000e000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    60.996] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    60.996] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    60.996] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    60.996] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    60.997] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.997]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    60.997]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[    60.997] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    60.997] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    60.997] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    60.997] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 2
[    60.997] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[    60.997] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    60.997] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 5
[    60.997] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    60.997] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    60.997] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    60.997] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    60.997] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    60.997] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    60.997] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    60.997] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    60.997] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.997]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.11
[    60.997]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.997]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    60.997] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    60.997] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    60.997] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.997]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 2.99.917
[    60.997]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.997]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    60.997] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    60.997] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    60.997] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.997]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.17.2
[    60.997]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.997]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    60.997] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    60.997] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    60.998] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.998]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    60.998]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.998]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    60.998] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    60.998] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    60.998] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.998]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    60.998]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.998]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    60.998] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    60.998] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    60.998] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 2
[    60.998] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[    60.998] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    60.998] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 5
[    60.998] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    60.998] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    60.998] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[    60.998] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    60.998] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    60.998] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[    60.998] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    60.998] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    60.998] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.998]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.11
[    60.998]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.998]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    60.998] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    60.998] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    60.998] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 0)
[    60.998] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    60.998] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    60.998] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.998]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 2.99.917
[    60.998]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.998]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    60.998] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[    60.998] (II) Unloading intel
[    60.998] (II) Failed to load module "intel" (already loaded, 0)
[    60.998] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    60.998] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    60.998] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.998]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.17.2
[    60.998]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.998]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    60.998] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    60.998] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    60.998] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[    60.998] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    60.998] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    60.998] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.998]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    60.998]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.998]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    60.998] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    60.998] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    60.998] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    60.998] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    60.998] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    60.998] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    60.998]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    60.998]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    60.998]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    60.998] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    60.998] (II) Unloading vesa
[    60.998] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[    60.998] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Thu Aug 28 03:57:48 2014 +0200
[    60.998] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    60.998]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    60.998]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    60.998]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    60.998]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    60.998]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    60.998]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    60.998]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    60.998]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    60.998]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    60.998]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    60.998]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    60.998]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    60.998]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    60.998] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
        i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
        915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
        Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
        GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    60.998] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[    60.998] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[    60.998] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[    60.998] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    60.999] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    60.999] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    60.999] (++) using VT number 7

[    60.999] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[    61.003] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    61.003] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    61.003] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    61.003] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    61.003] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    61.003]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[    61.003]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    61.003] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    61.003] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    61.003] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    61.003] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    61.003] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    61.003]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[    61.003]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    61.003] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    61.003] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    61.003] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    61.003] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    61.003] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    61.003] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    61.003]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[    61.003]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    61.003] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    61.003] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    61.003] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    61.003] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    61.003] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    61.003] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    61.003] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    61.003] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    61.003] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    61.003] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    61.003] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    61.003] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    61.003] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    61.003] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[    61.003] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[    61.003] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[    61.003] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    61.003]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.1.0
[    61.003]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    61.003] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[    61.003] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[    61.003] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[    61.004] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    61.004]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    61.004]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    61.004] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    61.004] (EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0xd00 out of range
[    61.004] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    61.004] (II) UnloadSubModule: "int10"
[    61.004] (II) Unloading int10
[    61.004] (II) UnloadSubModule: "vbe"
[    61.004] (II) Unloading vbe
[    61.004] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    61.004] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    61.004] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    61.004] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    61.004] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    61.004] (EE) 
[    61.004] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Anyone have any ideas what to try next?

Comment: Xorg.0.log from 4.4rc3 nomodeset nvidia mode

Comment: i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 and nouveau.modeset=0 results in the system starting up, but no output to screen. Either one of those options in place gets the same result. Neither in place and I get into X just fine, but resuming from suspend does not bring graphics up, but system is responsive from the network after resuming from suspend.

Comment: BIOS update to 1.1.3 makes no difference either.

Comment: Installed latest Intel firmware manually from 01.org
Re-ran Intel graphics installer

Booting with i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 I get the login screen but not at full 4K resolution. , when logging in screen goes black, but system still running. Init 3 && init 5 gets X11 visible again at login screen. but attempting to login again I get the KDE loading graphics, which appear to freeze without any blue in the progress bar. System still responsive over network, but interestingly a reboot command does not restart the computer, requiring a hard shutdown.

Comment: Booting without preliminary support or nouveau modeset, login screen comes up with 4K resolution, login works, but resume from sleep still doesn't bring the graphics up.

Booting with preliminary and nouveau modeset=0, low res login screen, login freezes on KDE loading graphics with the first bit of blue showing on the progress bar.

Comment: I also couldn't get my Skylake laptop to work with anything newer than 14.04 LTS with similar graphical issues. Tried 14.10, 15.04 and 15.10 and all of them couldn't even get pass the installation stage from Live CD. Also any 4.xx kernel couldn't work. In the end I settled with using 14.04. It's fine for me. If you want newer software you can always find trustworthy PPAs or build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Xiang Ji, 14.04 got me further. 14.04.3 gets me a laptop that successfully recovers from sleep! Unfortunately still not usable for two reasons. Firstly, the wifi doesn't work on the 3.x kernel, and from what I can find online 4.2 or newer is required to get it to work. Plugging in the 4.3.1 kernel causes the system to freeze after a while. Sounds like you stuck to the 3.x kernel, did you get wifi to work or just use a different wifi card?

Comment: Second issue is video playback. On both vlc and Dragon Player the video playback is stuttery, doesn't scale up even in full screen mode, and has tearing artifacts when the playback window is resized. I assume it's video drivers here, but the Intel drivers from 01.org don't support anything before 15.04. Looks like bumblebee might be worth a try, will give it a go later. Did you run into this? Thanks

Comment: Indeed I couldn't get wifi to work on 3.xx kernels. Currently I'm just using USB devices for wifi. Actually, my original external wifi card stops working after 5 minutes, so I'm just using tethering from a mobile phone at the moment. It works perfectly: the mobile phone itself is a good Wifi receiver, and on USB the transmission rate is fast.

Comment: Did you try installing `nvidia-355` driver? I couldn't get video playback to work on Intel either but when I'm running NVIDIA card using `nvidia-prime` it's fine.

Comment: Let me write my comments into an answer and let's discuss there I guess.

Comment: Thanks for that, was going to go down the Bumblebee route, but I'll try the straight nvidia prime stuff first. I'll get hold of a usb wifi adapter today and give that a try. Unfortunately the Dell is at home today, no room for 3 laptops on my desk at work, and it's now frozen, so I'll this all tonight. Thanks for the pointers, will let you know how I go.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Eventually I ended up going with Linux Mint 17.1 KDE (17.2 won't install directly), retrofitted with the 4.4rc5 kernel. Intel graphics drivers work after installing the Intel firmware from 01.org (driver itself from there won't install), and dist-upgrade. Video playback doesnt work (vlc or dragon both won't resize video playback and it's always on top). On the plus side sleep, audio and wifi all work. Virtualbox required ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test, gcc-4.9, virtualbox 5 and guest additions manually installed, but it works.

Comment: Going to try Kubuntu 16.04 LTS when it comes out (4.4 kernel planned for that release), but this config looks like it will work for me in the meantime. Resisting the temptation to try and get Nvidia working again, but it seems like a lost cause just now. Anyway, thanks for the info, helped to get me to a usable config in the end.

Comment: Glad it helped. So while kernels 4.2 and 4.3 didn't work, 4.4 worked for you? I might also try it out. Or do you think it's because you tried KDE over Unity? Also, if you found the answer helpful, you might choose it as accepted so that this question won't still appear as "unanswered".

Comment: I tried 4.2 as part of Kubuntu 15.10 I think, and 4.3 manually, neither worked. 4.4rc5 does work, although I'm getting intermittently kicked out of KDE back to the login screen. Think that's down to graphics drivers, which still aren't right. I didn't try Unity, always been a KDE guy. If I get the time tonight I'll try 16.04 daily via the live disk, but suspect it'll be the weekend before I get a chance to do an install.

Comment: 16.04 live daily (current as of 17th December) seems to work ok on this laptop. First boot off the live CD didn't work, was giving errors about stuck CPUs, rebooted with "nomodeset", which seemed to work ok, and a subsequent reboot without "nomodeset" came up fine. I've noticed this with other versions and Mint, so it's not 16.04 specific. inxi and glxinfo reported both gfx cards and drivers working. I put vlc on, but only had a very low res video that came with the release to try it with. I'll give it another go this weekend when I have access to my media collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite login loop with Nvidia proprietary graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/693454/infinite-login-loop-with-nvidia-proprietary-graphics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also couldn't get my Skylake laptop to work with anything newer than 14.04 LTS with similar graphical issues. Tried 14.10, 15.04 and 15.10 and all of them couldn't even get pass the installation stage from Live CD. Also any 4.xx kernel couldn't work. In the end I settled with using 14.04. It's fine for me. If you want newer software you can always find trustworthy PPAs or build it yourself.

Note that the newest Intel Wifi adapters might not work on kernels lower than 4.xx. I'm just using an external wireless card, actually USB tethering with an old mobile phone in my case as various wireless cards are known to be buggy with Ubuntu.

The Intel graphics card might have video playback issues. I installed the proprietary NVIDIA drivers from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`, via package `nvidia-355`. Video playback seems to be fine when I'm running Ubuntu solely on NVIDIA card. This option is configurable in `nvidia-settings` once the driver is installed.

Answer (score 4):

I followed liren's answer and got suspend working on my Inspison 15 7559 with Xubuntu 15.10, Linux Kernel 4.4, linux-firmare 1.56, nvidia-361.

I don't have enough rep to post a comment on liren's answer and it took me a while to fill in the blanks for each step. So, I thought it may save someone else some time who, like me, isn't experienced updating the linux kernel/firmware:

1. From Windows, update Dell BIOS to v1.1.5
2. Install Xubuntu 15.10

   - Boot from install media (Hit `F12` on BIOS splash)
   - When grub menu appears type `e`
   - Edit the line that starts with `linux` and add the `nomodeset` to the end of  the line
   - Hit `F10` to boot
3. Install Linux kernel 4.4:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily/linux-headers-4.4.0-040400_4.4.0-040400.201601101930_all.deb
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily/linux-headers-4.4.0-040400-generic_4.4.0-040400.201601101930_amd64.deb
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily/linux-image-4.4.0-040400-generic_4.4.0-040400.201601101930_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb
```

4. Install `linux-firmware` v1.56 from the Ubuntu 16.04 xenial repo

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main'
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install linux-firmware/xenial
$ sudo apt-add-repository -r 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main'
$ sudo apt-get update
```

5. Add `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` repo and perform a `dist-upgrade` (I don't know if this is necessary)

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

6. Install the Nvidia proprietary drivers

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
```

7. Remove `nomodeset` from the grub defaults in `/etc/default/grub`

   - Change the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LILNUX="nomodeset"`
   - to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LILNUX=""`

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
$ sudo update-grub
```

8. Reboot and try out suspend

---

Edits:

- Corrected command to add/remove linux-firmware xenial repo

Answer (score 0):

I have also settled on 14.04 after having no luck with later distros.

Though after much fiddling around I did manage to get the wireless to work with:
cp iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode iwlwifi-3165-9.ucode
cp iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode iwlwifi-3165-12.ucode

Generally I am a bit disappointed and really hoping some break through happens by the time 16.04 comes along.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Just install 16.04, problem solved. https://askubuntu.com/a/764979/409773

I've been running 15.10 on this laptop for some time. Here's how I made it work:

1. updated BIOS (did it from Windows)
2. ubuntu/xubuntu 15.10 (use "nomodeset" boot parameter before install)
3. latest linux-firmware package from 16.04 repo
4. kernel v4.5
5. oibaf repo
6. Intel Graphics Installer from https://01.org/linuxgraphics
7. nvidia-361
8. prime-select intel

I'm not sure if all these steps are necessary, but it worked.

By the way, I tried to install 16.04 with no success. It seems the problem won't be solved until 16.04.1 or 16.10 https://askubuntu.com/a/760124/409773

Answer (score 0):

Following Liren, didn't help at all. Dell 15 Inspiron 7559 is in a disaster
I did however manage to make quite a good progress with the following:
During, installing Ubuntu-Mate 15.10, and the first 2 boots, adding to the kernel:

```
i915.preliminary_hw_support=1
nouveau.modeset=0
```

- installing as usual.
during first boot, login to Terminal1 install of logging in.

> (use) Ctrl+Alt+F1

during ea. of the first 2 boots you do the following:

- First boot

  sudo apt-get remove nvidia* 
  reboot
- Second  boot

  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
  reboot

after that, the system loads up quite well however xorg keeps crashing from time to time.
Regarding the question of the thread OP, 
Ubuntu-mate 15.10 like that is quite stable, and randomly crashes on sleep\suspend
Xubuntu seemed to be doing better after sleep\suspend.
Still can't put my finger though on that xorg part.

Hope somneone can enlighten us with that part. (Gnome is acting the worst, i assume the load on xorg is heavier with a more complex gui <-- Not an ubuntu-expert

That's it.