# Ubuntu 16.04 Skylake not able to shutdown and restart

Tags: dell, shutdown, 16.04

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. I am facing shutdown issues often.
It hangs in a terminal with the message (sometimes shutdown works):

```
soft lockup, cpu#4 struck for 22s
```

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 with secure login turned off (as it prompted to turn off secure login to install third party drivers).

(Laptop model is Dell Inspiron 7550)

Comment: Also having this problem, with no solution in sight.

Comment: try installing graphics driver form additional software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Dell i7559 with i7-6700HQ and GTX 960M.

After a fresh install (boot directly to the installer with nomodeset, update all packages before logging in, # dpkg-reconfigure compiz), I got this cpu lockup issue.

Then I installed Nvidia driver 364.19 from https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa and everything (shutdown, reboot and suspend) works fine now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: its working after i choose nividia driver in additional software

Comment: Interesting, I got a MSI WS60, similar problem, also installed the nvidia-364. Now it does at least shutdown, but it takes a minute or so.

Comment: Any idea how to fix Intel graphics, though?

In my experience, the only way to fix this is to keep using nVidia instead of Intel, and this kills the battery.