# Cannot change resolution on my laptop, stuck at 4k on 15 inch screen - SOLVED

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm having some problems with my 16.04.1 Ubuntu instalation. To install I had to add nomodeset in live USB Grub. Then it installed correctly, however, everything is really tiny. I want to use Ubuntu at 1080p, not 4k, but settings don't have option for anything else other than 4k. I'm currently using some Intel HD 530 drivers, but I think they aren't really good.

xrandr returns

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 3840 x 2160, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 3840 x 2160
default connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   3840x2160     88.00* 
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x285) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
```

(The second option appeared after trying to manually add other screen resolution)

How do I solve this?

EDIT:

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/778009/603711) and it allowed me to have an option of 1920x1080 in Displays, but if I press apply, I get an error

```
The selected configuration for displays could not be applied 

required virtual size does not fit available size: requested = (1920, 1080), minimum=(3840, 2160), maximum=(3840, 2160)
```

Any ideas?

Updating:

[This](https://askubuntu.com/a/739545/603711) helped ^^ I just performed those steps after installing 4.6 kernel on 16.04.1 and now I have working Nvidia drivers which let me change the resolution.